# Removing Duplicates from a Matrix

Tags: octave

Let's say I have a matrix, where the values in in the first column are likely to repeat. Such as

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
1 3
 Etc...
```

I want to get a matrix where the duplicates are added together into one row, with the second column being the sum of the entires in the duplicate row. For example the matrix above should be

```
1 2+3
3 4
5 6
Etc...
```

Any idea how to accomplish this? Would it be better to try to edit in place or copy the values into a new matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to use `accumarray`. This, accumulating values in a new array, is the use case for the function. It will be much faster than a for loop and more readable (well, this is arguable. Many people also find it difficult but once you understand it, it's dead easy and very powerful):

```
octave> x = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 1 3];
octave> [y, ~, j] = unique (x(:,1));
octave> [y accumarray(j, x(:,2))]
ans =

   1   5
   3   4
   5   6
```

Note that the above will work even when your data is not integers. This is because we are using the last output of `unique()`, `j`, which are indices into the array of unique values `y`.

```
octave> x = [1.1 2; 1.3 4; 1.5 6; 1.1 3];
octave> [y, i, j] = unique (x(:,1));
octave> [y accumarray(j, x(:,2))]
ans =

   1.1000   5.0000
   1.3000   4.0000
   1.5000   6.0000
```

Comment: I would be one to debate readability:) But it's the proper solution none the less. However, I'd also debate "will work even when your data is not integers" as well. Consider the output of a matrix multiplication: in that case you can have many "unique" values which are the same up to machine precision. This is not what you generally desire.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I would have agreed with you about readability until I had to use it. Now it is natural. And on working with non-integers, values on the first column are different, therefore not `unique()`, therefore correct. If they are different because of floating-point rounding issues, then they need to be processed first (or indeed use a different approach) but that is a different issue from this question.

Comment: "*If they are different because of floating-point rounding issues, then they need to be processed first (or indeed use a different approach) but that is a different issue from this question.*". I disagree, this is an inherent problem with floats. This is what [I meant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769959/removing-duplicates-from-a-matrix/32770386?noredirect=1#comment53384216_32770386) by "less then trivial". But just for clarity: I also agree that your solution should be accepted, as both of our solutions are riddled with the floating-point problem (though both work for unique floats).

Comment: Wish I had been aware of this before; incredibly useful!

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the rows of the summed matrix don't matter *and* you only have integer values, you could use `unique` to check each individual value in your first column. Like this:

```
m = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 1 3]; %original matrix
mvals = unique(m(:,1)); %unique of first column

mnew = zeros(length(mvals),size(m,2)); %preallocation
for k=1:length(mvals)
   mnew(k,:) = [mvals(k), sum(m(m(:,1)==mvals(k),2:end),1)]; %sum each row where first is mvals(k)
end
```

Comment: Yes, that does work for integers. No particular reason to worry about the order of the rows; you can sort by rows afterwards so it isn't a problem. I wonder what a more general solution would look like that could accept and deal with floating-point values.

Comment: @EliRiekeberg, it was just laziness that I did it this way. The standard way to treat floats is to use `abs(m(:,1)-mvals(k))<tol` with some finite, small `tol`, and do the same. **Edit**: Well, yeah, the `unique` part would be less than trivial.

Comment: the standard way is to use `accumarray`. it's in the function name, it accumulates an array. And if you don't have integers that you can use as index, then you use the final output of `unique` which creates them for you.